# Construct a matrix out of multiplied submatrices efficiently

Tags: r, matrix

I want to construct a matrix like (where A is a real matrix and I is the identity matrix):

[image]

I don't want to use a for loop. I tried things like:

```
sequence = 1:T
sapply(sequence, function(i) matrix(A%^%(i-1)))
```

but failed. I thought of creating the first matrix column in the picture and continue to copy calculated matrices diagonaly, but I have no idea how to realize this.

**Edit:** I'm very sorry for the trouble I've caused. Here is what I'm looking for in a quick and dirty for loop

```
library("expm")

n<-5

A<-matrix(1, 2, 2)
output <- matrix(0, 5*2, 5*2)

for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in i:1) {
    output[(2*(i-1)+1):(2*i),(2*(j-1)+1):(2*j)] = A %^% (i-j)
  }
}
```

Comment: quick and dirty loops are often the way to go...

Comment: ps you should post your solution as an answer in the answer section rather than as an edit to your question

Comment: The problem is, that I want to run the loop from above in a time sensitive simulation study - so I have to code as fast as possible. The above solution was just to give an example of what I was trying to do. There is on the one hand the downside, that the calculation of A^i (for i as a arbitrary natural number) is done over and over again. I corrected this in my recent answer. But I think the process could be much faster with apply like functions.

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with something else :

```
library("expm")

n<-5
A<-matrix(1, 2, 2)

output <- matrix(0, 5*2, 5*2)
output2 <- matrix(0, 5*2, 5*2)

start.time <- Sys.time()
for(dummy in 1:2000){
  for (i in 1:5) {
    for (j in i:1) {
      output[(2*(i-1)+1):(2*i),(2*(j-1)+1):(2*j)] = A %^% (i-j)
    }
  }
}
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken

start.time <- Sys.time()


for(dummy in 1:2000){
  for (i in 1:5) {
    output2[(2*(i-1)+1):(2*i),1:2] = A %^% (i-1)
  }

  rowLength = dim(output2)[1]

  for (i in 2:5) {
    output2[(2*i-1):rowLength,(2*i-1):(2*i)] = output2[1:(rowLength-(2*(i-1))),1:2]
  }
}
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

This is (on average) a little bit faster, but I think with some built in function magic the result can be even better. Perhaps someone could help ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been looking at `lower.tri(x, diag = TRUE)` documented at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lower.tri.html?

I have made an example of how you can apply it [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=muECLLt6&version=3)

The steps are:

```
A <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5)  # construct the initial matrix
B <- A * lower.tri(A)    # convert A to a lower triangular matrix of booleans (with TRUE below diagonal, FALSE from diagonal and up)
B <- B * A + diag(5)     # construct the final result
B
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just looked at it, but I can't figure out how to set the row dependent exponent of my matrix with it. Also I tried to use it with sapply, but I did get a messed up vector instead.

Comment: @user241879 I have just attached an example of the function applied.

Comment: @user20650 The example I have provided is using a square matrix. Can you give me an example of how the output is different from what is expected?

Comment: sorry i removed comment ... my initial thought was that `A` would have to have the following number of elements to fill the lower.tri... `n_lt <- function(n) 1/2 * n*(n+1) ; n_lt(1:5)` (ie if identity is dimension 5, the lower.tri has 15 elements, so A has to have 15 elements, which cant happen for a square matrix obviously). However, i then think i misinterpreted the question ... It seems to have full matrix A repeated in the off diagonal, and A to the power. etc, rather than just elements

Comment: No problem, I missed the exponent, so my answer is not going to solve the problem. I leave it here in case some ideas from it can be used.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried to play around with the lower.trig function, but couldn't figure out how I can use it to get my desired end result. I also updated my question to show what I'm exactly looking for. Thank you anyway !